# Converting infinitely nested objects in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

**EDIT:** I originally worded this question very poorly, stating the problem was with JSON serialization. The problem actually happens when I'm converting from my base classes to my returned models using my custom mappings. I apologize for the confusion. :(

I'm using .NET Core 1.1.0, EF Core 1.1.0. I'm querying an interest and want to get its category from my DB. EF is querying the DB properly, no problems there. The issue is that the returned category has a collection with one interest, which has one parent category, which has a collection with one interest, etc. When I attempt to convert this from the base class to my return model, I'm getting a stack overflow because it's attempting to convert the infinite loop of objects. The only way I can get around this is to set that collection to null before I serialize the category.

Interest/category is an example, but this is happening with ALL of the entities I query. Some of them get *very* messy with the loops to set the relevant properties to null, such as posts/comments.

**What is the best way to address this?** Right now I'm using custom mappings that I wrote to convert between base classes and the returned models, but I'm open to using any other tools that may be helpful. (I know my custom mappings are the reason for the stack overflow, but surely there must be a more graceful way of handling this than setting everything to null before projecting from base class to model.)

Classes:

```
public class InterestCategory
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Interest> Interests { get; set; }
}

public class Interest
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long InterestCategoryId { get; set; }
    public InterestCategory InterestCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Models:

```
public class InterestCategoryModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<InterestModel> Interests { get; set; }
}

public class InterestModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public InterestCategoryModel InterestCategory { get; set; }
    public long? InterestCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping functions:

```
public static InterestCategoryModel ToModel(this InterestCategory category)
{
    var m = new InterestCategoryModel
    {
        Name = category.Name,
        Description = category.Description
    };

    if (category.Interests != null)
        m.Interests = category.Interests.Select(i => i.ToModel()).ToList();

    return m;
}

public static InterestModel ToModel(this Interest interest)
{
    var m = new InterestModel
    {
        Name = interest.Name,
        Description = interest.Description
    };

    if (interest.InterestCategory != null)
        m.InterestCategory = interest.InterestCategory.ToModel();

    return m;
}
```

This is returned by the query. (Sorry, needed to censor some things.)

[image: nested objects]

Comment: do you use Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: @YuriTceretian I do, but only to the extent that it's now integrated with .NET Core. For example, I'm returning from controllers using `return Ok(model);`, I'm not manually serializing with `JsonConvert`.

Comment: I know I've hit this before, and I think we created a DTO model that collapsed the information and capped it, basically making it easier for other systems to consume vs. being in our database/EF format

Comment: Try to return object using method Json(model, serializerSettings).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not .NET Core related! JSON.NET is doing the serialization.

To disable it globally, just add this during configuration in `Startup`

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    }));
```

**edit:**

Is it an option to remove the circular references form the model and have 2 distinct pair of models, depending on whether you want to show categories or interests?

```
public class InterestCategoryModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<InterestModel> Interests { get; set; }

    public class InterestModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

public class InterestModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public InterestCategoryModel InterestCategory { get; set; }

    public class InterestCategoryModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Note that each of the models has a nested class for it's child objects, but they have their back references removed, so there would be no infinite reference during deserialization?

Comment: In initial message, author mentioned that he set up that option. But after editing, it disappeared.

Comment: I had that in my original question, but edited to clarify. I realize it was still ambiguous, I just edited it further. I'm sorry. :/ Is there a way to put my custom mappings in with JSON.NET instead of my own classes? Would that even help?

Comment: @vaindil: Is it an option to remove the self referencing in the models as shown above?

Comment: @Tseng I hadn't even thought about that. I should probably do that, have a distinct class for each individual return type. That would solve my problems at the expense of a bit more complexity, but it's much better than manually looping through my lists of nested objects to null the back references. Thank you so much!